# Selenium File Chooser with a hidden input[type=file]

Tags: selenium, file-upload

I have a image file upload and want to test it with *Selenium (java)*. The user have two options. He can push the image with drag and drop from his local machine or he can click "Browse..." button. Then appears the browser specified file chooser.

In *Selenium* I tried different things. To my knowledge *Selenium* does not serve operations out of the browser. So to test the drag and drop functionality is not a possible solution.

So I tried to click the Browse button and work with the browser specified file chooser. I found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXhi5QwY4mk) where someone successfully pick a file on this dialog. He took the Robot class to do something on the keyboard.

```
getDriver().findElement(By.id(BROWSE_BUTTON)).click();

Thread.sleep(5000);

StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("C:\\A.JPG");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

When I debug this lines, the test is pending after the click() method in line 1. 
I use *Firefox 31.1*.

Any ideas? Maybe there are some alternatives?
To write the file path in the `input[type='file']` is no alternative because this input is hidden.

Comment: What type of element is the Browse button?

Answer (score 2):

Hidden file input has not been an issue with *Firefox* or *Chrome*. And, *v2.45.0.6* makes sure the *IE* works with hidden file input as well. So simple `sendkeys()` using `input[type='file']` should be fine for you. See [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG)

**EDIT**

For FF it could be a compatibility issue as well. But, latest version of FF is not yet supported by `Selenium`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383949/upload-picture-element-is-not-currently-visible/30384313#30384313)

**2nd Edit**

Selenium 2.46 has been released and IEDriver should work with hidden file input tag now.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("uploadFile")).sendKeys("C:/A.JPG"); doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you please provide html and the stacktrace?

Comment: HTML: <input id="uploadFile" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" multiple /> Nothing added at console at line: driver.findElement(By.id("uploadFile")).sendKeys("C:/A.JPG");

Comment: The test doesn't fail but no image uploaded. In Firefox there is no input visible, only a 'Browse..' button.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. BTW, try chrome instead see what you get

Comment: What the ... Chrome is working. But we don't want to edit the test profile. Must have stable configuations. Maybe we do a backend test and leave out a selenium test here. Anyway: Thanks for your support.

Comment: Ok now it is working in Firefox too. Method sendKeys() needs the absolute path of the file. I wrote the path as string in the method. That worked only in Chrome but not in FF.