# Current IE doesn't support file upload using Selenium Webdriver 2.42.000

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, file-upload

Currently I was able to upload the file using selenium webdriver version 2.42.00 with browser chrome while I couldn't able to do it the same with Internet Explorer version 11.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("fileUpload")).sendKeys(filePath);
```

where `id = fileUpload` is for input element with `type=file` and this field is a hidden field.

Any thoughts on it:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 30 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
>   System info: host: 'XXXXXXX', ip: '192.168.12.24', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
>   Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=true, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:7704/ takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
>   Session ID: cfa81fae-4ea2-43b9-9e3a-69135462fe82
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue with IEDriver which is going to be resolved in next release. Hidden file input tag will not work on IE as it does on other browsers. See the issue logged [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3858). I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574916/selenium-file-chooser-with-a-hidden-inputtype-file/30575093#30575093)

**EDIT**

Here is the good news. Just confirmed the Selenium version 2.46 has the changes. See [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG). So upgrade and it should work