# Issue with file upload in selenium webdriver browser ie10

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, saucelabs

Facing an issue with file upload in ie browser ,its working fine in firefox and chrome but not in ie.Am using below code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/ng-form/card/fieldset/div/div[9]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/ng-form/label/div/span[2]")).sendKeys("/home/FF41/application.ini");
```

It is not showing any error ,instead of sendkeys if we give click its opening a new window.so xpath is working fine,but why it fails in ie even the xpath is correct.

**Absolute xpath**:

`//html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/ng-form/card/fieldset/div/div[9]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/ng-form/label/div/span[2]`

no error but file upload not done.

**relative xpath**

```
 //*[@id=\"c0-Attachment-8\"]
```

not visible element exception

HTML Code:-

```
<input id="c0-Attachment-8" class="targetx-file-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched ng-valid-required" type="file" ng-class="{'ng-touched' : attName !== undefined }" ng-required="fileRequired" ng-disabled="success || attName" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" accept="" ng-model="filename" name="c0-Attachment-8"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML code for this? Which error are you getting?

Comment: <input id="c0-Attachment-8" class="targetx-file-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched ng-valid-required" type="file" ng-class="{'ng-touched' : attName !== undefined }" ng-required="fileRequired" ng-disabled="success || attName" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" accept="" ng-model="filename" name="c0-Attachment-8"/>

Comment: If am using absolute xpath its not showing any error //html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/ng-form/card/fieldset/div/div[9]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/ng-form/label/div/span[2] but if i use relative xpath path it throws error not visible element

Comment: Please edit the question and add these things in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using ie10 so it's obvious that you are working on windows.

Now Sendkeys needs absolute path of the file while you have mention path of file like linux directories

You are using path like this:-

```
/home/FF41/application.ini
```

While you need to give path like windows pattern :-

```
C:\\Users\\Easy\\Desktop\\testfile.txt
```

So try with

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/ng-form/card/fieldset/div/div[9]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/ng-form/label/div/span[2]")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Easy\\Desktop\\application.ini");
```

You also need to click on upload button after above operation

Comment: am using setFileDetector for this purpose.Actually am using sauce labs to run my tests

Comment: I never tried with setFileDetector.. Try with above example . It should work for you :)

Comment: Its working on others site but the site which am testing fails

Comment: can you please upload any pic manually on the element and click DOM what on which attribute it showing your file name. If it has been track then you can use javascriptexecutor

Answer (score 0):

Try by using below xpath :

```
//input[@id='c0-Attachment-8']
```

Comment: Element is not displayed

Comment: Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, ElementNotVisibleException.class);
  WebElement element = (WebElement) wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='c0-Attachment-8']")));
  element.isDisplayed(); Does this help?

Answer (score -1):

Another best option is to use SendKeys Class (in System.windows.form namespace)
It can work with any of the browser.
You can use the following code:

```
        drv = new InternetExplorerDriver("path to IE Driver Server exe");
        drv.Navigate().GoToUrl("your URL");
        drv.FindElement(By.XPath("enter your xpath here")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("complete file path to upload");
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        drv.FindElement(By.XPath("submit button xpath")).Click();
```

This code is in C#. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Which selenium IE Driver version are you using ?
Is it same as this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897718/current-ie-doesnt-support-file-upload-using-selenium-webdriver-2-42-000

Comment: am running it in sauce labs

Comment: Can you try one more thing : segregate sendkeys method

like:

IWebElement ele = drv.FindElement("ByXpath");
ele.SendKeys("your value");

i have resolved many errors by using this approach.

Comment: what is  IWebElement? I is it der?

Comment: Please ignore IWebElement , it should be WebElement. Please reply if it works?

Comment: its not working.the click is working its opening a new window to take file, but file is not uploaded.Am using remotedriver to run my script am running it on saucelabs cloud its working fine in firefox and chrome but fails in ie